# Actionscript function for x^y in a calculator

Tags: java, actionscript-3, math

I am working on a simple calculator with 2 input fields, some buttons (+,-,*,/,^,sqrt)

Any idea what function I could use for the x^y option?
I mean something like: you input '3' in first field, you choose '^' option and input '3' in second field, and get 27 as answer?

I just need the mathematical function, no code, something like math.square(y) or something, no idea...

Comment: Are you writing in `actionscript`? Is the `java` tag relevant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use this:

```
Math.pow(x,y)
```

Source & more information:
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/actionscript-the-definitive/1565928520/re114.html

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the [`Math`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html) class, [`Math.pow()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#pow()) for the specific case